# Python: Assign values to first observation of each group in DataFrame

Tags: python, group-by, pandas

Why in Python, using Pandas, we cannot use the following to assign a value to the first observations of each group?

```
df['A'].groupby(df.ID).first()==0

or

df['A'].groupby(df.ID).first()==np.nan
```

where the DataFrame looks like:

```
ID  A  
1   2
1   1
1   .45
2   .14
2   3
2   4
```

In other words, I want

```
ID  A  
1   0 or NaN
1   1
1   .45
2   0 or NaN
2   3
2   4
```

`cumcount` does not work for me though I have installed Pandas 0.13. Like others, Pandas 0.13 gets installed with errors and I want to avoid to deal with Pandas 0.13.

Comment: whaat is the problem with installing 0.13? (0.13.1 is the current version FYI)

Comment: @Jeff I have difficulties to do a proper installation of 0.13.1 of Pandas. I don't know why and also the super computer that I am using does not have 0.13.1

Comment: does it happen to be a s390x? create virtual env then you can just ``pip install pandas==0.13.1``

Comment: So I type `pip install pandas==0.13.1` in pip-Win 1.6 it never gets installed. How can I create a virtual env? Thanks @Jeff

Comment: http://dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/

Comment: This might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22210865/python-assign-values-to-first-observation-of-each-group-in-dataframe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
In [24]: df = read_csv(StringIO(data),sep='\s+')

In [25]: df
Out[25]: 
   ID     A
0   1  2.00
1   1  1.00
2   1  0.45
3   2  0.14
4   2  3.00
5   2  4.00

[6 rows x 2 columns]

In [26]: df.loc[df.groupby('ID',as_index=False).head(1).index,'A'] = np.nan

In [27]: df
Out[27]: 
   ID     A
0   1   NaN
1   1  1.00
2   1  0.45
3   2   NaN
4   2  3.00
5   2  4.00

[6 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are likely getting what you want if you assign it to a new df or modify it to do an inplace change...
df.replace(1.5, nan, inplace=True)